# stop output from printing twice

Tags: java, printing, superclass

i have some code below that prints the output twice. how do i only print the bottom two lines without printing `car1.print();` `car2.print();` as well. i believe it has to be part of the `super.print();`

```
class Car extends Vehicle {
   public String type;
   public String model;

   public Car(int theCapacity, String theMake, String theType, String theModel) {
      super(theCapacity, theMake); 
      type = theType;
      model = theModel;

      super.print(); 
      {
         System.out.println("  type = " + theType);
         System.out.println("  Model = " + theModel);
      }
   }
}


class Task1 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Car car1 = new Car(1200,"Holden","sedan","Barina");
      Car car2 = new Car(1500,"Mazda","sedan","323");
      car1.print();
      car2.print();
   }
}
```

Comment: whitout deleting code, you can't :)

Comment: The `{}` isn't doing anything. Whatever is inside is just part of the constructor. Not too sure what you really need here.

Comment: You have a method `print()` in your class `Vehicle`, I guess... Why do you call it in the constructor of `Car` (by `super.print()`) **and** explicitly print their values afterwards (by `car1.print()` and `car2.print()`)? Just get rid of one of these calls... Another idea would be to provide a proper `toString()` in each class and print that.

Comment: could you add actual and expected result?

Comment: Can you add the expected output as well, to the question

Comment: if theres a way to rewrite the super.print section so it doesn't print car1.print(); and car2.print(); that would be much appreciated

Comment: the question asks "Modify the class Car to include a print method which invokes its parent’s print method
(by making use of super) and prints out the type and model."

Comment: Please show us the super class `Vehicle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the `print()` method in the class `Car` using `super.print()` like you implemented the constructor of `Car` using the constructor of the super class `Vehicle`.

Have a look at this basic example implementation (for which I had to guess the design of the class `Vehicle`):

```
public class Vehicle {

    protected int capacity;
    protected String make;

    public Vehicle(int capacity, String make) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.make = make;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Capacity: " + capacity);
        System.out.println("Make: " + make);
    }
}
```

In the class `Car`, just override the method `print()` and call `super.print()` at first followed by printing the members that `Vehicle` does not have:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {

    private String type;
    private String model;

    public Car(int capacity, String make, String type, String model) {
        super(capacity, make);
        this.type = type;
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        super.print();
        System.out.println("Type: " + type);
        System.out.println("Model: " + model);
    }
}
```

You can try that in some `main` method in a solution class:

```
public class TaskSolution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle car = new Car(1200, "Holden", "sedan", "Barina");
        Vehicle anotherCar = new Car(1500, "Mazda", "sedan", "323");

        System.out.println("#### A car ####");
        car.print();
        System.out.println("#### Another car ####");
        anotherCar.print();
    }

}
```